# C String with size

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I have this code in C.  The function needs to know the length of the string.  Is there no way for me to pass just the string and then, inside the function, get the size?

```
char text2[] = "Hello!!";
write_coord_screen(2, 2, text2, sizeof(text2), FB_BLACK, FB_WHITE);
```

Comment: hae you looked at the strlen function?

Comment: You are writing dicey code if you depend on your calling function to pass you a null-terminated string. You can call strlen() in your function BUT if there is no null for strlen to find... you are opening yourself up to malicious behavior.

Comment: @nicomp: yes, sort of, but mostly no.  Null-terminated strings are completely normal in C and not automatically a security risk.  Let's put it like this — if you are not going to trust null-terminated strings, you can't use the standard C library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can someone break into your house? Yes, but mostly no. :)

Comment: This way even an explicit string length parameter has to be trusted. But if the caller lies ?

Comment: @nicomp Good luck using C and doing things like opening any file.  Or using any of the `exec*()` functions. Or interacting with the process environment.  Or processing command-line arguments.

Comment: You can use `strnlen` to limit the function from wandering too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [strlen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html). Notice however, that `strlen` is a `O(n)` operation, so if you know the length of the string (as you do in the above example) it may be preferable to pass that directly instead of computing it.

Also, in the above example, `sizeof(text2)` will be 8, but the length of the string is 7. `sizeof` will take into consideration the nul terminator, but usually when we talk about the length of a string we talk about the number of characters it has.

On top of this, `sizeof` only works in your case because `char text2[]` declares a character array. If instead you'd have written `const char *text2 = "Hello!!"` you'd be forced to use `strlen`.